# Unity C#: type error referencing float from another script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, reference, floating-point

I'm new to Unity, and although I've looked this up a million times, I can't get my script to stop erroring. I am trying to reference a public float (attached to a different object) in a new script - which is simple, I know. I have tried various methods, but this is what I have so far. I keep getting the error that the *float (currentHealth) cannot  be implicitly converted to 'Health'*, which I understand but cannot seem to fix.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public class sugarGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject sugar;
    public GameObject Insulin;
    public Transform generationPoint;
    public float distanceBetween;

    Health PlayerHealth;

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Awake ()
    {
        GameObject.FindWithTag("Main_Girl_0");
        PlayerHealth = GetComponent<Health>().currentHealth;
    }
}
```

Comment: `PlayerHealth` is not a `float`, it is `Health`. You cannot assign a `float` (the type of `currentHealth`) to a `Health`. I'm not familiar with Unity, but did you perhaps mean to do `PlayerHealth = GetComponent<Health>();`?

Comment: It would help if you also showed us the Health class.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb That'd be it! Can't BELIEVE I didn't spot that!

Answer (score 4):

Based on my comment:

`PlayerHealth` is not a `float`, it is `Health`. You cannot assign a `float` (the type of `currentHealth`) to a `Health`.

I'm not familiar with Unity, but perhaps you meant to do:

```
PlayerHealth = GetComponent<Health>();
```